# C++ Class Header and Implementation Error

Tags: c++, class, header-files, interface-implementation

I just recently started messing around with separate class files in c++ and this was my first attempt:

First I made a class header called "ThisClass.h":

```
//ThisClass.h

#ifndef THISCLASS_H
#define THISCLASS_H

class ThisClass
{
private:
    int x;
    float y;

public:
    ThisClass(int x, float y);
    void setValues(int x, float y);
    int printX();
    float printY();
};
#endif // THISCLASS_H
```

Then, I implemented my class in a file called "ThisClass.cpp":

```
//ThisClass.cpp

#include "ThisClass.h"

ThisClass::ThisClass(int x, float y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void ThisClass::setValues(int x, float y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

int ThisClass::printX()
{
    return this->x;
}
float ThisClass::printY()
{
    return this->y;
}
```

Finally, I made a file called "main.cpp" where I used the class:

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        ThisClass thing(3, 5.5);
        cout << thing.printX() << " " << thing.printY()<< endl;
        thing.setValues(5,3.3);
        cout << thing.printX() << " " << thing.printY()<< endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I then compiled and ran this program through Code Blocks which uses the MinGW compiler and received the following errors:

```
In function 'int main()':|
main.cpp|7|error: 'ThisClass' was not declared in this scope|
main.cpp|7|error: expected ';' before 'thing'|
main.cpp|8|error: 'thing' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Am I somehow doing this wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That fixed my errors. However, now my console isn't outputting anything even though I have 2 cout calls.

Comment: What console? Are you using Visual Studio or some other IDE or just command line?

Comment: I am using Code Blocks which uses the MinGW compiler.

Comment: Strangely it works fine if I run it straight through MinGW without the Code Blocks IDE, so I'll have to figure that out myself. Anyways it works so I'll give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Found out that my problem was that I had added the flag -mwindows which disables the console. I just had to uncheck the flag and everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `#include "ThisClass.h"` in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered that you forgot to put `#include "ThisClass.h"`in `main.cpp`.

Just do that and your code will be compiled. 
 I just want to answer your question -
 **However, now my console isn't outputting anything even though I have 2 cout calls**
  Please put a `getchar()` before `return` in `main` function, it will allow you to see your output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the real reason the console wasn't working was because i added the flag -mwindows which adds libraries that disable to console.